# How can I read Excel data in batches in springboot

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have large Excel file that I imported using Spring. The data is bulky, so I want to read the data in batches. I'm thinking of reading 10-20 rows per Excel sheet. How can I go about it? I heard of Spring Batch, but I'm not sure how it works.

Below are the dependencies I used

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not sure Spring Batch is your best option here but you might give it a try. I personally would rather use Apache POI and go for streaming here (SXSSF workbooks). For a summary have a look here (and look for the streaming section): https://dzone.com/articles/anatomy-of-java-poi-library-for-excel-file

Comment: The SXSSF worksbooks only write

Comment: @mohlehpa That is incorrect, SXSSF will only **read** Excel files, not write them.